# To what extent is denormalization necessary in Cassandra?

Tags: mysql, database, optimization, cassandra, database-normalization

I'm in charge of migrating an application from MySQL to Cassandra. And I'm curious, to what extent is denormalization necessary in this process?

For example, if the program searches for an index in table A, then looks up that value's information in table B, is this not allowed in Cassandra, or just not optimal? There are no joins in the application, just several lookups like this.

The resources I've found online confuse me. Do I *need* to denormalize the data by combining these tables together, or is this just something that speeds up performance in Cassandra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually in a relational database like MySQL you design your tables to efficiently store your data, and then you normalize those tables to eliminate redundant information, to save storage space, and to prevent having inconsistent data (like having different addresses for a person in different rows).  Then almost as an afterthought, you can figure out what queries you want to do against those normalized tables by doing joins and adding indexes on any column to make those queries fast.

With Cassandra you approach it first by figuring out what queries you need to do, and then designing your schema to do those queries efficiently.  The query options in Cassandra are far more limited than in MySQL, since all you really have to work with is the partition key and the clustering columns.  You can't easily do joins, you can't easily aggregate, and search options are very limited.  You can create secondary indexes, but using them is not efficient like RDBMS indexes, so generally you want to avoid them and rely mostly on the compound primary key.

So no, you do not *need* to denormalize your data completely, but it is a useful tool in the toolbox for making frequently used queries efficient.  It's basically a way of grouping a lot of related information into one bucket that you can access quickly by the key.  Storage is considered cheap, so generally we don't care if we have some redundant information in multiple tables (within reason).

When you say a program "searches" for an index in table A, that sounds inefficient since you can't easily search for things in Cassandra tables.  What you want is for the program to know the key for what it is looking for so that Cassandra can go directly to the place where that information is stored.  For example, if a user logs into a system, you use their userid to access the bucket of information that tells everything about them.

Now it is perfectly acceptable to have a foreign key in table A that you use to look up other related information in table B, since that is just two key reads, one for table A and then one for table B.  But if rather than doing this two step look up occasionally for individual rows, you actually need to join all the rows of table A and B for generating a report, well then you'd be better off combining them into one denormalized table.

Answer (score 1):

Data Modeling in Cassandra is a bit more than "Denormalizing your tables" and I would recommend going over a more detailed talk on the subject before you set out on any migration.

That said, It is *absolutely necessary* that you reevaluate any schema you have so that it fits into the working parameters of Cassandra. Choices around partitioning and clustering keys will either make or break your use case. You must make sure that you model your queries, and that there is a table with an appropriate key for every query you want to perform.